# Servlet mapping by Regex

Tags: java, regex, google-app-engine, servlets, restlet

I'm trying to figure out a way for a Restlet Application to be `serve` by Guice.

**My code looks like this:**

```
public class GuiceServletModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {

        bind(RemoteApiServlet.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        bind(ServerServlet.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

        serve("/_ah/remote_api").with(RemoteApiServlet.class);
//        serveRegex("^((?!_ah).)*$").with(ServerServlet.class, map("org.restlet.application", "com.mycompany.MyRestletApplication"));
        serve("/*").with(ServerServlet.class, map("org.restlet.application", "com.mycompany.MyRestletApplication"));

    }

    private static Map<String,String> map(String... params) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(params.length % 2 == 0, "You have to have a n even number of map params");
        Map<String,String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i+=2) {
            map.put(params[i], params[i+1]);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

**Why am I doing this?** The reason is the `MyRestletApplication` have routing for ROOT `/` and `/rest/` so plainly using the *web.xml* to serve `MyRestletApplication` via:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is causing the `_ah/*` paths (which are GAE admin paths) not reachable or more precisely caught by the RestletServlet. E.g. `/_ah/admin` would not work anyore. Thus, I am thrying to do some `serveRegex` such that Restlet will not catch `_ah/*` paths.

Now, serving the Restlet servlet in `/*` make the `MyRestletApplication` work fine.
However server with regex like this: `serveRegex("^((?!_ah).)*$")` makes the `MyRestletApplication` fail to work.

Looking at the logs:

> [INFO] Feb 12, 2015 3:47:45 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter
>   afterHandle [INFO] INFO:
>   2015-02-12    03:47:45    127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1   8080    GET /rest/stuff -   404 -   0   77  http://localhost:8080   Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/37.0  http://localhost:8080/

Its showing 404 there, why is that?

Comment: Strange, as script handlers will never match '/_ah/' [1], so having <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> should not be an issue. Are you able to log within the RestletServlet that '/_ah/*' is actually being handled by it? [1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Reserved_URLs